# Isn't it possible to call methods inside @html elements?

Tags: c#, razor

I am trying to set different properties depending on access in my view. Below are two examples currently in my code:

1.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "form-control", id = "x", @readonly = User.HasAccess() ? "false" : "readonly" })
```

2.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Animal, Model.Animals, new { @class = "form-control", id = "x-dropDownList", disabled = User.HasAccess() ? "false" : "disabled" })
```

I know with several examples that the method works, for example when you write out the if statement (though I think the code above is more satisfying and easier read than multiple if statements everywhere), but the ones with access still can't write in the textbox even though they should be able to. As a user with access I cannot use the textbox as I want because it is still readonly though it shouldn't.

**So I am wondering if it is a thing that method calls (which are not a js function or such) can't be called inside a @html element. Is there something I can do to make this work without doing anything outside the view itself? (not change any method and so on)**

I appreciate you help!

Comment: This does work, as it's a valid C# expression. Your problem must be somewhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no issue using the method call or ternary operator in Razor.

Your issue is with the generated HTML.

`readonly` and `disabled` don't take Boolean values; they are applicable by simply being present, as is demonstrated here:

```html
<input readonly="true" value="true" />
<input readonly="false" value="false" />
<input readonly value="attribute only" />
<input value="attribute omitted" />
```

You should notice that only the fourth input is not readonly.

Answer (score 0):

If the expression is valid, as it appears to be, the data is returning something that prevents the controls from being rendered the way you expect them to.

At the top of the view, capture User.HasAccess() in a variable within a razor script block. Set a breakpoint after you've done so and inspect its value in a debugger. Chances are, the user doesn't actually have access based on the method's return value.

Answer (score 0):

A solution that worked for me:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, User.HasAccess() ? new { @class = "form-control", id = "x" } : (object) new { @class = "form-control", id = "x", @readonly = "readonly" })


@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Animal, Model.Animals, User.HasAccess() ? new { @class = "form-control", id = "x-dropdownlist" } : (object)new { @class = "form-control", id = "x-dropdownlist", disabled = "disabled"})
```